# Zend\Db (ZF2) equivalents of ZF1's findParentRow(), findDependentRowset(), etc

Tags: php, database, zend-framework2

In ZF1, `Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract` provides methods such as `findParentRow()`, `findDependentRowset()`, etc. These methods can be used to retrieve row objects from linked tables using a `$ruleKey` specified in the `$_referenceMap` of the corresponding table class.

What are the equivalent methods in ZF2? Could it be that this functionality is still missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such things do not exist anymore. Zend Framework in its second version went back one step from providing full ORM possibilities and rather provided a good QueryBuilder. I.e. everything under `\Zend\Db\Sql\*`

If you want ORM-Features, you're best advised to use a great ORM. There are a few really good ones out there, including [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) and [Doctrine2](http://www.doctrine-project.org/). The later one already enjoying a great implementation into Zend Framework 2 via the Module [doctrine/DoctrineORMModule](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule).

Using a full ORM has many advantages with one being the awesome Documentation both Propel and Doctrine provide. Doctrine also provides compatibility with [mongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/). So you may want to give one of those a try ;)

Comment: I'm somewhat disappointed by the lack of basic ORM stuff, which in ZF1 was entirely sufficient for my purposes. I'm refactoring a complex application from ZF1 to ZF2 and it seems I'll end up with a mix of third party components rather than a clean ZF2-only solution.

Comment: Third party isn't necessarily bad. Considering Doctrine has a great implementation into ZF2 and it does it's job multiple times better. While the implementation in ZF1 was .. well, okay .. it lacked a lot of stuff and the performance was plain bad. Good ORMs solve that.